# Spark AR Studio on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there a way to install Spark AR Studio on linux? I tried through wine but it doesn't work. Spark AR Studio is available for MacOS and Windows but I want to know if there is some way to install it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

For now, the best way to use Spark AR on your computer is use dual boot, one for Linux and one for Windows 10. I've same problem as you, and I've tried almost all possibilities and none of them work in Linux. So, try using dual boot.

If you have a powerful PC, you can try to use a virtual machine hypervisor like Virtualbox and installing Windows on it, then install Spark AR inside.

Comment: I installed SparkAR in a Win10 VirtualBox, inside Debian. When it runs, characters are all glitched/broken/bad. Also, 3D view was... upside down , I don't know why. Inusable.

Comment: I had the same issue with characters and upside down 3D view... Someone figure out if there is some way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to emulate it on Arch Linux in VirtualBox of Windows 10 64-bit (free) with Enable PAE/NX (you gotta enable it in BIOS to give more resources to your VM) and enable 3D Acceleration under Display.

However, the performance was better in VMware with less glitches.

Downgrading version of Spark AR assuming you don't need minor new features, increased the performance.

Comment: I installed SparkAR in a Win10 VirtualBox, inside Debian. When it runs, characters are all glitched/broken/bad. Also, 3D view was... upside down , I don't know why. Inusable. Do you know about this?

Comment: @MarioMey yes, basically, like in my answer "the performance was better in VMware with less glitches." and from what I understand this is due to your drivers that the VirtualBox is using which are not optimal for your hardware. It would make sense that in a proprietary VMware it is better since they are more actively maintained for heavy duties requirement of Augmented Reality! I also tried downgrading version of Spark AR which also works - the versions increase so fast because they change a lot of internals which are not necessarily following open source standards for AR libraries...